# Extend/append python join list

Tags: python, list, extend

I have an example:

```
li = [['b', 'b', 'c', '3.2', 'text', '3', '5', '5'], ['a', 'w', '3', '4'], ['a', 'x', '3', '4'],['a','b'],['312','4']]

a = 0
b = []
c = []
count = []
for x in range(len(li)):
    for a in range(len(li[x])):
        if li[x][a].isalpha():
            a += 1
        elif not li[x][a].isalpha() and li[x][a + 1].isalpha():
            a += 1
        else:
            break
    i = (len(li[x]) - a)
    b.extend([' '.join(li[x][0:a])])
    b.extend(li[x][a::])
    count.append(i)


for x in range(len(count)):
    a = count[x] + 1
    z = (sum(count[:x]))
    if x == 0:
        c.append(b[:a])
    else:
        c.append(b[a+1::z])


print(c)
```

I have various items in the `li` list and the length of the list itself is not constant.
If any element in the array is a string or if there is some other symbol between the two strings, it combines everything into one element - this join works as I wanted.

I would like to preserve the existing structure. For example, output now looks like this:

`[['b b c 3.2 text', '3', '5', '5'], ['a w', 'a x', 'a b', '4'], ['a w', '4'], ['5', '4'], ['a w', '']]`

but it should look like this:

`[['b b c 3.2 text', '3', '5', '5'],['aw','3','4'],['ax','3','4'],['ab'],['312','4']`

Of course, the code I sent did not work properly - I think of a solution but I still have some problems with it - I do not know how to add ranges to this list `c` - I try to pull the length of the elements of the list as `count` but it also doesn't work for me - maybe this is a bad solution? Maybe this extend `b` is not the best solution? Maybe there is no point in using so many 'transformations' and creating new lists?
Let me some tips.

Comment: what if a number between strings?

Comment: Find the first point in the execution where the state of the variables is not what it is supposed to be & say why. (Debugging fundamantal.)

Comment: @komatiraju032 if a number is between strings, it should be appended - but I don't think I will have other cases like this working join.

I just want to keep the post join structure as it was before, but I don't know exactly how to do it.

Comment: what is the output for this `['a', 'b', 1, 2, 3, 4, 'c', 5, 'd']`?

Comment: @philipxy do you propose a solution with some True / False flag and then change this list? I thought about it but this solution will probably also be related to counting the number of elements that should be in one list and I still have a problem with it.

Comment: @komatiraju032 in this case it should be: `['a b 1 2 3 4 c 5 d']` - but I never take `int` there - it will always be a `string` number, just like: '1', '2' etc. However, I will not have such cases - it will be one or two numerical characters on the string, for example: `['a','b','3','0','d','1','2','3']` - output: `['a b 3 0 d', '1', '2', '3']`  or `['a','b','3','d','1','2','3']` - output: `['a b 3 d', '1', '2', '3']`

Comment: Do what you need to trace execution. Research debugging. PS Clarify via edits, not comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition is a bit unclear to me, but I think this will do it. Code is not very verbose, though. If it does what you intended, I can try to explain / make it simpler.

```
li = [['b', 'b', 'c', '3.2', 'text', '3', '5', '5'], ['a', 'w', '3', '4'], ['a', 'x', '3', '4'],['a','b'],['312','4']]

def join_to_last_text(lst: list, min_join: int = 1) -> list:
    last_text = max((i for i,s in enumerate(lst) if s.isalpha()), default=min_join - 1)
    return [' '.join(lst[:last_text + 1])] + lst[last_text + 1:]

output = [join_to_last_text(lst) for lst in li]
print(output)

# You can join a minimum of first items by setting a higher max default.
# If max does not find isalpha, it will use this value.
output_min_2 = [join_to_last_text(lst, min_join=2) for lst in li]
print(output_min_2)
```

Comment: it will not work if list start with number `['312','4', 'x', 'y']`

Comment: this solution is very good. Thank you. May I have the explanation of this construction:`(lst: list) -> list:` -  or some tutorial? Is this like a pointer in C ++? 
What if I want to add a additional `if` - i.e. if the first element is a 3-digit number and the second element is a digit, then it should combine - `['123', '456', '1','123','431']` - output: `['123 456', '1', '123', '431']`. Do the usual condition that if the first element is a number character and its length is 3 and the next element of the list is also a number then do join? Will it work this way or it's work differently?

Comment: @komatiraju032 check out my answer.

Comment: @DeepSea This is basically telling the datatype of the variable. `def func(a: b)` means that in function `func`, argument `a` is of type `b`.  Whereas `def func(a,b) -> c` means that function `func` returns a value of type `c`

Comment: @DeepSea: Those are called type annotations. It will help whoever is looking at the code to understand what types are expected. If you use a modern IDE, it probably has support for those and will tell you if you call a method using the wrong type.

Comment: @DeepSea: If you want to always join the first two elements, set the max default to 1. I'll update my answer to show you.

Comment: I have found such an exception and if in all cases it works as it should, in this case it crashes - example: https://ideone.com/8rfnMg how do you add exceptions to this? So, for example, if the string has a digit or some special characters like `+, -, /` etc.? `isalpha()` don't get it and it's False. I tried to make such a list with exceptions and add a condition to the existing `if`: `if s in special_list` -> then do join. However, this does not help Output should be like: `[['3bbc3.2text', '3', '5', '5'], ['a+w', '3', '4'],['ax/s', '3', '4']`

Answer (score 1):

@Johan Schiff's code works as expected but leaves a corner case - when the first element of the list is not a text. I have made a small change in his code to take care of that situation:

```py
li = [['b', 'b', 'c', '3.2', 'text', '3', '5', '5'], ['a', 'w', '3', '4'], ['a', 'x', '3', '4'],['a','b'],['312','4']]

def join_to_last_text(lst: list) -> list:
    first_text = min((i for i,s in enumerate(lst) if s.isalpha()), default=0)
    last_text = max((i for i,s in enumerate(lst) if s.isalpha()), default=0)
    return lst[:first_text] + [''.join(lst[first_text:last_text + 1])] + lst[last_text + 1:]

output = [join_to_last_text(lst) for lst in li]
print(output)
```

Where would this give a different output(a correct one)? Check out the following test case:

```
li = [['4','b', 'b', 'c', '3.2', 'text', '3', '5', '5'], ['a', 'w', '3', '4']]
```

@Johan's code would output -

```
[['5bbc3.2text', '3', '5', '5'], ['aw', '3', '4']]
```

whereas based on the following phrase in the question

> If any element in the array is a string or if there is some other symbol between the two strings, it combines everything into one element

the output should be-

```
[['5', 'bbc3.2text', '3', '5', '5'], ['aw', '3', '4']]
```

Comment: Please look at my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61886823/extend-append-python-join-list/61887312#comment109461177_61887312)

Comment: @DeepSea I don't get what exactly you want to say. Though I have understood this- You want to add additional conditions. The condition is - Join the first two elements if they are three-digit numbers (ofc in string form). Is it what you want to ask?

Comment: Nice tweak. Depends on what result you want, obviously. This is what I meant by definition being unclear. :)

Comment: @paradoxlover yes for example: `li = [['456','2341','0','2','4'], ['a', 'w', '3', '4']]` output should be like: `[['456 2341', '0','2','4'],['a w', '3', '4']]`  
or the solution I wrote about - checking `isalpha` and then a string - in this case if the first element is numeric characters with length `>= 2` and the next element is also a numerical character with length`>= 2` then it should be combined. Where to add such `inf` only for `[0]` elemnt in list?

Comment: @paradoxlover 
I just came up with another solution I won't need it anymore - if there is a different case, I will probably come up with something. 
Thanks again for your help paradoxlover and Johan Schiff - I will analyze this code, it taught me a lot.

Comment: @DeepSea Welcome. in case the answer helped, you could consider upvoting it.

Comment: @paradoxlover it does not work as it should - I have found such an exception and if in all cases it works as it should, in this case it crashes - example: https://ideone.com/8rfnMg how do you add exceptions to this? So, for example, if the string has a digit or some special characters like `+, -, /` etc.? `isalpha()` don't get it and it's False. I tried to make such a list with exceptions and add a condition to the existing `if`: `if s in special_list` -> then do join. However, this does not help
Output should be like: `[['3bbc3.2text', '3', '5', '5'], ['a+w', '3', '4'],['a+w', '3', '4']

Comment: I solved the problem - just add regex `regex = re.compile('\+|^\d\w|[a-zA-Z]\d|\w\/\w')` and  then add `or regex.match(s)` on `if` statement